# How to automatically change network adapter settings upon new network

Tags: networking, windows-8, network-adapter

I am connecting to many different networks on a regular basis.  Some use DHCP and the other requires a static IP to be set in different network classes (10.x.x.x, 192.168.x.x)

Is there a way to set the network adapter to change when a new network is selected (similar to profiles in wicd)

Just to be clear, what I am doing currently now is opening properties on my adapter ->  Internet Protocol Version 4 -> Properties -> Then flip between DHCP settings and use the following IP address.

This is also problematic as the static IP is cleared when I select DHCP.  So I need to keep a list of valid IPs as well.

I am aware of alternative configuration as mentioned [Automatically picking network settings based on the wifi network](https://superuser.com/questions/26368/automatically-picking-network-settings-based-on-the-wifi-network) and [Static and dynamic networks on the same network adapter](https://superuser.com/questions/599485/static-and-dynamic-networks-on-the-same-network-adapter), but I require more configurations than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the tool [NetSetMan](http://www.netsetman.com/) to have different profiles.

[image]

You can switch to different profiles which a rightclick on the trayicon of the tool.

Answer (score 0):

Up to now I use [NetProfiles](http://code.google.com/p/netprofiles/). Did not know NetSetMan, but looks interesting, too.

Comment: It looks like a great and up and comming project, but there seems to be a lot of windows 7 and windows 8 issues that still have been unresolved.

Comment: I have to confess that I use it on XP (where it works nicely), while the question has a Win8 tag - true.